# Terminal plugins for easy ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, zsh

I have to connect to many server machines by `ssh` into them.

But if I didn't use terminal for some time, connections are getting disconnected. Now I have to close my terminal and login again with `ssh`.

Are there any plugins which does help me in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are built in functions in ssh solving your purpose.

From `man ssh_config`:

> ### ServerAliveInterval
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

By default, keep alives are disabled but you can enable them for a single connection by passing the *ServerAliveInterval*-Parameter with the `-o` Option:

```
ssh -oServerAliveInterval=<time in seconds> <rest of your ssh command arguments>
```

If you like having this configuration for all of your SSH connections. It's easier to put the following in your  `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval <time in seconds>
```

Furthermore there is a second parameter affecting the keep-alive-behaviour: `ServerAliveCountMax` (see `man ssh_config`).

I've found a nice article about the *ServerAlive*-Parameter: [How to Keep Alive SSH Sessions](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/)